# Multiple wordpress loops not showing data

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I am trying to add another loop to my template and the post id's are coming from a custom field saved into `$field` but the code below is not getting into the while loop. Also the post id's are for a content type called portfolio.

**Why is the code below not pulling and showing the post based on the id's I am passing the query?**

```
       <?php
    $field = get_field("use_case_ids", $currentPostID);

    $post_list = $postArray = explode(',', $field);

    foreach( $post_list as $post_id ) :
    $querypost[] = query_posts('p='.$post_id);
    endforeach;

    foreach( $querypost as $key => $postData ) :

  while ($postData[$key]->have_posts()) : $postData[$key]->the_post();

    $postData[$key]->the_title(); 


endwhile;
endforeach;
wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

**EDIT:** I had to turn my dynamic value `$field` into an array. But the page still breaks and when I remove the following lines of code the rest of the page loads

```
 while ($postData[$key]->have_posts()) : $postData[$key]->the_post();

    $postData[$key]->the_title(); 


endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code if it is usefull :

```
    <?php
    $field = get_field("use_case_ids", $currentPostID);
    echo $field;
    $post_list = array($field);
    foreach( $post_list as $post_id ) :
    $querypost[] = query_posts('p='.$post_id);
    endforeach;

    foreach( $querypost as $key => $postData ) :
    while ($postData[$key]->have_posts()) : $postData[$key]->the_post();

    $postData[$key]->the_title(); 

    endwhile;
endforeach;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

I think this will work.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the information. Something is wrong with the code because the rest of the page is not rendering after this is called. But I am not seeing any errors. Weird.